# Separate Power Pivot Data Model and Power Pivot Report from Single Workbook

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Initially, we have created Power Pivot report in workbook, containing Source Data Model as well.

Now, we want to convert workbook having model as Shared Data Model, and all report needs to be part of single workbook.

I want to implement one of the below solution, but know how to do it.

1. Separate and export all Power Pivot report sheet into single Excel Workbook such that it will have all report sheets.
2. Use same model as it is and delete reports from existing one after export to new Excel workbook.

OR

Is there is any other way to avoid re-creation of reports again? I want to use same report but instead of embedded Excel data source, I want to use shared data source in Excel.